# Gitlab-Runner | x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, x509certificate, gitlab-runner

I'm trying to build then push image on gitlab container registry but i found below issue i'm using on premise Gitlab instance and the Gitlab runner is ubuntu that using shell executor
I appreciate if someone can help to solve this issue
Thanks a lot in advance

[gitlab-runner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j221.png)
[config.toml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oKbC.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the `daemon.json` file, whose default location is `/etc/docker/daemon.json` inside gitlab-runner:

```
{
  "insecure-registries" : ["gitlab.example.com:5050"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Telinov for your efforts i just want to share with you that the kubernetes cluster is using container.d and these are the configurations that i set trying to solve the issue but it failed with the same issue :
path : /etc/containerd/config.toml

```
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs]
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."gitlab.example.com:5050"]
      insecure_skip_verify = true
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.headers]

  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors]
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."gitlab.example.com:5050"]
      endpoint = ["https://gitlab.example.com:5050"]
[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".x509_key_pair_streaming]
```

then
systemctl restart containerd         on all the kubernete nodes

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem after adding the above configurations and i found the secret that i've created with wrong username for the gitlab but after adding the gitlab container registry on all the worker nodes and modifed the docker-registry secret everything is okay now  but without your guidance i wouldn't solve it .

kubectl create secret  docker-registry my-registry-key --docker-server=$CI_REGISTRY --docker-username=$GITLAB_USER --docker-password=$GITLAB_PASSWORD -n gitlab-test --dry-run=client -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -

[image: Pod is running]